# min value of field in array and 1st object in array mongodb aggregation query

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Let me use following pseudo example to better explain my need.

I have a group of people and some images which belong to group schema

```
{
  images:['ARRAY OF IMAGES'],
  members:[{
    age:NUMBER,
    name:STRING, 
    email:EMAIL_OF_MEMBER
  }], 
  groupName:String
  ....etc
}
```

Now i have a aggregation query

```
group.aggregate([
  {
    $project:{
       //some code happening to support query in the below $match
       'original':$$ROOT
    }
  },
  {
    $match:{//some query code happening and all params from $project above will be available here.  the $original field contains all fields of document}
  },
  {
    //Now i want to extract 1st image from Images array, Min and Max age of members in group.
  }
],function(err,results){//dosomething with results})
```

If I don't use 3rd pipeline I am getting the whole document which is not required for me. I just need 1 image and min-max age of people in group to display a web page. I don't need other details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below part of the query will gives you the first image as well as min and max age of the members.

```
db.[collection].aggregate([
                            { 
                              $unwind : "$members" 
                            },
                            { 
                              $group : 
                                     { _id: "$_id" , 
                                       images : { $first: "$images"},
                                       minAge : {$min : "$members.age"},
                                       maxAge : {$max: "$members.age"}
                                     }
                            }
                          ]).pretty();
```

For the **mongoDb Version 3.1.6** and above, you can use [$Slice](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6074) in aggregation pipeline to limit the contents of array.

```
db.[collection].aggregate([
                            { 
                              $unwind : "$members" 
                            },
                            { 
                              $group : 
                                     { _id: "$_id" , 
                                       images : {$push : "$images"},
                                       minAge : {$min : "$members.age"},
                                       maxAge : {$max: "$members.age"}
                                     }
                            },
                            { 
                              $project : 
                                       { images : 
                                           { images :{$slice:1} }
                                       },
                                       minAge : 1 ,
                                       maxAge  : 1
                           }
                         ]).pretty();
```